# Loan Payment Formula Terminology

Tags: loans, terminology

Consider the following formula:

```
Payment = P * ([r * (1 + r)^n] / [([1 + r]^n) - 1])
```

Do any parts of this expression (not single variables) have a name? For example, `(1 + r)^n` repeats. Is there a name this section could be replaced with?

The idea is to simplify this formula using any understood industry or mathematical terms.

Comment: Did you get the formula right? The tricky term seems to cancel, leaving payment = Pr.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_function

Comment: Keep in mind, even though something might have a name, if it's not in common use, you'll need to explain it every time you use it. I teach high school math, and use that exact (1+r)^n and its variations frequently, but have never called it that. It was simply part of the compound interest lecture.